# How to make a numpy array from an array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, dimensions

I'm experimenting in `ipython3`, where I created an array of arrays:

```
In [105]: counts_array
Out[105]: 
array([array([ 17,  59, 320, ...,   1,   7,   0], dtype=uint32),
       array([ 30,  71, 390, ...,  12,  20,   6], dtype=uint32),
       array([  7, 145, 214, ...,   4,  12,   0], dtype=uint32),
       array([ 23, 346, 381, ...,  15,  19,   5], dtype=uint32),
       array([ 51,  78, 270, ...,   3,   0,   2], dtype=uint32),
       array([212, 149, 511, ...,  19,  31,   8], dtype=uint32)], dtype=object)

In [106]: counts_array.shape
Out[106]: (6,)

In [107]: counts_array[0].shape
Out[107]: (1590,)
```

I would like to obtain a plain `shape=(6, 1590), dtype=uint32` array from this monster I created.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) -

```
np.vstack(counts_array)
```

Another way with [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
np.concatenate(counts_array).reshape(len(counts_array),-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]: 
array([array([68, 92, 84, 35, 14, 71, 55, 40, 21, 41]),
       array([30, 90, 52, 64, 86, 68, 61, 85, 26, 98]),
       array([98, 64, 23, 49, 13, 17, 52, 96, 97, 19]),
       array([54, 26, 25, 22, 95, 77, 20, 73, 22, 80]),
       array([15, 84, 91, 54, 25, 21, 37, 19, 25, 25]),
       array([87, 17, 49, 74, 11, 34, 27, 23, 22, 83])], dtype=object)

In [24]: np.vstack(a)
Out[24]: 
array([[68, 92, 84, 35, 14, 71, 55, 40, 21, 41],
       [30, 90, 52, 64, 86, 68, 61, 85, 26, 98],
       [98, 64, 23, 49, 13, 17, 52, 96, 97, 19],
       [54, 26, 25, 22, 95, 77, 20, 73, 22, 80],
       [15, 84, 91, 54, 25, 21, 37, 19, 25, 25],
       [87, 17, 49, 74, 11, 34, 27, 23, 22, 83]])
```

Comment: Thanks. According to `%timeit` in ipython, on my data, your `concatenate` way is twice as fast as my `array` way. The `vstack` way is more than 4 .5 times slower.

Comment: @bli Awesome ! Good to see some runtime numbers there! Not surprised by those, as `vstack` would internally use `concatenate`.

Comment: And `vstack` has to first reshape each array to 2d.

Comment: @hpaulj That makes sense then for the timings, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After various experiments, it turns out that the following simple syntax just works:

```
numpy.array([sub_array for sub_array in counts_array])
```

My first working version was unnecessary complicated:

```
numpy.array([[*sub_array] for sub_array in counts_array], dtype=numpy.uint32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered `numpy.vstack()`?
I use it very often for this kind of operations.